# Rally rest API transactions

Tags: rest, transactions, rally, appsdk2

Is there any way to achieve an atomic transaction using the Rally wsapi. I know a transaction implies state among the consecutive requests, but REST obviously is a stateless protocol. So that might be an issue.

need to be able to pull a `portfolioitem/feature` and then immediately write it back if I have the most recent version of it. I have a custom field on `portfolioitem/feature` that WILL be edited by multiple people simultaneously, and I need to make sure that each update happens in the correct order.

Since i don't have access to Rally's server stuff, i must do all this client side, and I can't figure out how to do this. I will be doing this will the Rally SDK also.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think WS API supports atomic transactions. A scenario where updates occur as one atomic transaction so that, for example, if one of the updates fail they are all rolled back is not supported. In the example you mentioned each update will be a distinct transaction and in case of a mid-air collision when the same artifact is updated by different users, one of the users will receive a concurrency error.

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same boat as the OP, the only difference being that hours may pass between the read and subsequent write. Interestingly, I only seem to get concurrency errors when I attempt to update a record while there's another transaction of mine in flight. I don't see any exception raised when I am updating a record using a stale version thereof, i.e. one that someone else has changed from under me.

I will be attempting to fix this soon as it's becoming an issue. The chosen approach is to forcibly chain a GET before every POST, and throw an exception if the VersionID of the record I GET doesn't match the one I have stored in-memory. In case of mismatch, it will refresh the local record (and thus, view) and prompt the user to resubmit their changes. Yes this will be inconvenient for a user but in my app most changes are a single click away so it's reasonable.

I too would like to know if there is a better approach to this problem. One would assume that with every record having a VersionID, it would be handled server-side, with proper support from WsapiProxy on the client end. Maybe I'm missing something obvious, like explicitly fetching VersionID?